# Can not Place Order, Is it Migrate JS Error at Magento 2.2.7 Error?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, jquery

I have installed Magento ver. 2.2.7 for A MarketPlace Site also Purchased MarketPlace Extension and Installed it Successfully.

***Before Order Place was working, But Now click on Order Place Button, The loader starts and Stops. No Order Being placed.***

When i checked the console, I found :

```
jquery-migrate.js:41 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:41
get @ jquery-migrate.js:58
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
jquery-migrate.js:43 console.trace
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:43
get @ jquery-migrate.js:58
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9
```

***No Error is Showing, How can I Trace the error? Please Suggest.
Thanks in Advance.
What could be the probable errors & How can we solve this?***

Answer (score 0):

The error may occurred due to static contents.

You can try steps describe below.

1) Set Magento 2 developer mode.

```
sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

2) Remove Static Content and Cache files.

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/generation
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
sudo rm -rf var/static/frontend/*
```

3) Try forced Content Deploy

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

4) Give permission to pub, var, generated

> sudo chmod -Rv 777 pub var generated